# Eliminar scroll de un md-select no funciona

Tags: angularjs, scroll

Tengo el siguiente código en Angular 1.X:

```
 <md-input-container style="margin:0; overflow-y: hidden !important;">
        <label>STATUS</label>
        <md-select style="overflow-y: hidden !important;" ng-model="query.filter.status">
        <md-option ng-repeat="status in statuses" ng-value="
{{status.key}}"><span>{{status.val}}</span></md-option>
        </md-select>
    </md-input-container>
```

Actualmente cuando se selecciona el elemento se abre una lista con **scroll** de 7 elementos. He intentado ya poniendo `max-width` altos y `overflow-y: hidden;` en todos lados y no hay manera.

En la documentación no he encontrado nada para deshabilitar el scroll.

¿Alguien sabe qué me falta?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hay que sobrescribir los max-height en el .css que vienen predefinidos por AngularJS (Angular 1) de la siguiente manera:

```
menu {
    max-height: none !important;
}


content {
    max-height: none !important;
}
```

cabe decir que sin el `!important` nunca reescribirá los valores.

Comment: Si! Los containers tenian max-height puesto. Esto lo ha resuelto :)

Answer (score 1):

Prueba esto:

```
overflow-y: hidden !important;
```

Comment: Ya lo he intentado con !important y tampoco funciona.

Comment: bueno, habría que analizar si que existe un contenedor anterior el cual muestra este listado. Probablemente ese sea el que tiene el scroll auto

Comment: He mirado ya a través del developer tools de chrome el contenedor (que es un md-content) y no tiene ningún overflow-y asignado. he intentado ponerlo y ni así funciona...

Comment: será posible verlo online? para analizarlo?